# What does the 5-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ explicitly look like?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I found three $5 \times 5$ matrices that fulfil the defining Lie algebra relation of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$:

[image]

However, these matrices are not antisymmetric, which implies that when we put them into the exponential map, the corresponding group-element matrices are not orthogonal. This seems strange because $SO(3)$ is defined as a set of orthogonal elements.

*Is my explicit representation wrong? Or am I wrong to assume that $SO(3)$ elements have to be orthogonal?*

Any link to a reference the displays the five-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this [blog entry](http://visuallietheory.blogspot.com/2013/07/real-representations-of-lie-algebra.html) I tried to answer a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356141/real-representations-of-lie-algebra-mathfrakso3/437037).

Comment: @user71769 that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Your other posts also look extremely helpful.

Comment: I didn't check your matrices, but note that if conjugate each matrix in a representation by a fixed invertible matrix $A\in Gl(5)$, then you get an equivalent representation.  But if $X$ is anti-symmetric, there is no reason that $AXA^{-1}$ should be antisymmetric.  I'm willing to bet that there is some specific $A\in Gl(5)$ for which $A\tilde{T}_i A^{-1}$ *is* antisymmetric for all $i\in \{x,y,z\}$, but, again, I didn't actually verify this.

Comment: You seem to be expecting that **every representation** $\mathfrak{so}_3 \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_n$ (here, $n=5$) has image in $\mathfrak{so}_n$ which is clearly false as per @JasonDeVito's comment. Something can be saved along the lines of what he writes though. Cf. also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/322860/96384

Comment: Note that another way to find a (not "the") matrix represenation of the $\mathbf 5$ ist to recall that, by $\mathbf 3\otimes\mathbf3=\mathbf3\oplus\mathbf5\oplus\mathbf1$, the 5d representation can be constructed as $3\times3$ symmetric traceless matrices on which the defining 3d representation acts from both sides. So you can pick a basis of 3d symmetric traceless matrices and just see how the generators act.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the representation you found. The eigenvalues of your matrices are, indeed, *±2i,±i,0*, the ones required for the "spin-2" quintet of [physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins).

You may check directly that the quadratic Casimir is an invariant, 
$$
T_x^2+ T_y^2+T_z^2= -6 ~ 1\!\! 1, 
$$
as expected, 
so that it *must* be equivalent by some similarity transformation (for you to find) to the spherical basis representation linked, as well as the tasteful [antisymmetric matrix representation](http://visuallietheory.blogspot.com/2013/07/real-representations-of-lie-algebra.html) proffered by @user71769 's blog,
\begin{equation}  
t_y =  
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & -\sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\\ 
t_z =  
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\\ 
t_x = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{3} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} ~.
\end{equation}

Such basis changes are routine for the [triplet representation](http://visuallietheory.blogspot.com/2013/07/real-representations-of-lie-algebra.html), and are detailed in Wikipedia, but I know of no pressing applications for your quintet one.

Just because the geometrical definition of SO(3) involves orthogonal matrices, there is no good reason for all representation matrices  to be orthogonal.